# Registry good practice (C)

Tags: c, winapi, registry

If i want to read a variable string out of the registry with RegGetValue is it good practice to do it like this?

```
DWORD dwByteCount=20,dwType;
char *value = (char *)malloc(dwByteCount);
HKEY hKey;
LONG lResult;

while(TRUE){
  lResult = RegGetValue(hKey,
              "somesubkey",
              "somevalue",
              RRF_RT_REG_SZ,
              &dwType,
              value,
              &dwBytesAllocated);
  if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    break;
  }
  else if(lResult == ERROR_MORE_DATA){
    free(value);
    dwBytesAllocated+=20;
    value = (char *)malloc(dwBytesAllocated);
  }
  else {
    free(value);
    return NULL;
  }

}
```

Comment: Good pratice as in? Readability? No. Concision? Neither. Error safety? Nope.

Comment: I'd double the allocated size rather that add 20 to it.  Doubling reduces the operation to O(n) time, adding requires O(n^2) time.

Comment: There is not reason to change the value in `dwBytesAllocated` at all.  If `GetRegValue` returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, `dwBytesAllocated` will be set to the required number of bytes.

Comment: @Wug: Assuming that `n` is the size of the value, and that you are measuring the number of iterations of the loop, I'd say that adding requires `O(n)` and doubling reduces it to `O(log(n))`.

Comment: @rodrigo: It's amortized constant time.  What's the sum of 1/2^n?

Comment: @Wug: Amortized time has little to do here. I think the correct question is: how many times do I have to multiply `x` by 2 for it to be greater than `n`? Or: how many times do I have to add 20 to `x` for it to be greater than `n`?

Comment: @rodrigo: I'd typed up this big long thing, only to realize that I wrote "constant" and meant "linear" so my bad.  I'll post it anyway:  Please consult the behavior patterns of C++ and Java map insertions, vector pushes, and StringBuilders, which are all based on this behavior.  If you do it with additive scaling, you will allocate 20 + 40 + 60 + ... + N bytes (N^2/40, N/20 groups of average size N/2).  If you do it with multiplicative scaling, you will allocate N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ... bytes (2N, the sum of 1/2^x from x=0 to x=infinity).